# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400 angular delete

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

When I try to call `delete` method in angular I received the error below.

> Failed to load http://localhost:56065/api/Regists/5: Response for
>   preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400

Here my component.ts file.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http ,RequestOptions,Headers} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  reId;
  options: RequestOptions;
  header: Headers;
  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onCli(){
    this.header = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    });
    this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.header });
    this.http
    .delete('http://localhost:56065/api/Regists/'+this.reId.toString(),this.options)
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: did you enable cors in the rest api side?

Comment: yes, I had enable cors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use services for these kind of stuff , components are not completely comfort for http requests,

try to make service:

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Injectable()
    export class tableService {
     private serverUrl:string= "http://localhost:56065/api/Regists/";
private headers=new Headers({
    });
      constructor (
        private http: Http
      ) {
    this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    this.headers.append('Authorization', 'if token');
    this.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
    return headers;
}

     delete(data: any): Observable<any>{

        let url = this.serverUrl + '/' + data.id;
      return this.http.delete(url,{headers: this.headers}).map(res => res.json()).catch(err => {
  return Observable.throw(err);
})
      }

    }
```

just call service method :

```
this.service.delete(this.deletedData).subscribe(res => {
          console.log('deleted Success');
          console.log(res);
        }
```

Comment: Actually I want to do it using  components are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable cors on server try following in your web api's `Global.asax.cs`  file

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            if (Context.Request.HttpMethod != "OPTIONS") return;
            Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", Context.Request.Headers["Origin"]);
            Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,x-access-token");
            Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            Context.Response.End();
        }
```

Comment: How can you tell which server-side software package the OP is using?

Comment: @BeetleJuice bcs he added asp.net-web-api in his question tags

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
onCli(){
this.header = new Headers({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
});
this.http
.delete('http://localhost:56065/api/Regists/'+this.reId.toString(),{headers: this.header})
.subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
},
error => {
  console.log(error);
});

}
```

Comment: Have you enabled the CORS?

Comment: Enabled/setting cors from angularjs wont help you..You need to enabled in Backend code..or else you can use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en